# html javascript collapse/expand table rows,child rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to collapse/expand table rows when I click on row. I am adding rows and child rows dynamically by `javascript`. Here is my screenshot

[image]

Here in image you can see two button i.e `Add rule and add comments`. when I click on add rule it add on parent row. when I select parent row and click on add comment it add child row.

There are 5 rows. First row i.e. `cell in row 0`  it contains three child rows `child row 0,child row 1,child row 2`. And in `child row 2` it contains it's own `child row 3`.

Here `javascript` code to collapse/hide rows

```
function GetSelectedRow(obj) 
{
    trID = obj.id;
    var SelRow = document.getElementById(trID);
    SelRow.setAttribute("bgcolor", "#808080");
    //return obj.id;
    //alert(trID);

    var children = getChildren($(obj));
    $.each(children, function () {
        $(this).toggle();
    })
}
//---------------- get all child element to collapse-------------
function getChildren($row) {
    var children = [], level = $row.attr('data-id');
    while ($row.next().attr('data-parent') == level) {          
        children.push($row.next());
        $row = $row.next();
    }
    return children;
}
```

When I click on parent row i.e. `cell in row 0` it calls the method `GetSelectedRow` and collapse all it's child row(`child row 0, child row 1, child row 2`). But the problem is in sub child rows(`child row 3`). It is not collapsing. See here is my collapsed image.

[image]

Here in image you can see I have selected first row and it collapse all child row but issue in `subchild`. How can I collapse all the rows including `child and sub child`?

**EDIT** 
Here is my html code

```
<input type="button" onclick="AddRule()" value="Add Rule" />
<input type="button" onclick="AddComments()" value="Add Comments" />
<table id="myTable" class="collaptable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rule Discription
            </th>

            <th>Primary Module
            </th>

            <th>Model
            </th>

            <th>Shop Call Number
            </th>

            <th>EWR
            </th>

            <th>Suggested Rule Effective Date
            </th>

            <th>Rule Contents
            </th>

            <th>Reason
            </th>

            <th>Rule Note
            </th>

            <th>Level
            </th>

            <th>Children
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="mybody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jsFiddle** Link https://jsfiddle.net/18uxxnuc/

But I am not getting why it is not working there. I have added all code there.

I think I have to use like `recursive` function.

**EDIT**

I tried jquery plugin [aCollapTable](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Creating-Collapsible-Table-Rows-aCollapTable.html) and [github](https://github.com/alvaroveliz/aCollapTable) I have added this function in my AddComment method. but the issue is, it is adding +/- each time when I add child row. See [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td37ba7f/) demo. I don't know why this plugin aCollapTable is not working there.

Comment: Can you provide your html too? If possible a fiddle will be great..

Comment: See my edit. Actually I am adding these rows on button click. I will added fiddle also

Comment: Can  you add JsFiddle to replicate the issue? that way it would be easier to resolve this

Comment: @AjayPunekar Please create `JSfiddle`. Not the one you attached as image.. Atleast code to replicate the issue.. JS functions `AddRule()` and `AddComments()`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Ok wait. I will create.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao See my fiddle link. Actually I am not getting why it is not working there. But you can see my all code there.

Comment: @Reddy See my fiddle link.

Comment: You forgot to add `jquery script` and wrap your `JS` code in `head`. I have done that, but **[`Its working as expected right?`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/18uxxnuc/1/)**

Comment: No. It's not collapsing all rows. See my second screenshot. It collapse all child row but not sub child.

Comment: @Reddy Please see this fiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/18uxxnuc/1/  `Guruprasad` corrected it.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).on('click','tr',function(){

$(this).slideToggle()

})
```